# Number of isosceles obtuse-angled triangles with perimeter $2008$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Find the number of all integer-sided isosceles obtuse-angled triangles with perimeter $2008$.

My efforts:

let sides be $x$, $x$, $y$ so $2x+y=2008$ , but by triangle inequality $y<2x$ also since it is obtuse-angled we can $y>x$.

these were my deductions, so how do I proceed further? any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can continue with saying that $y<1004$ and if $2y$ is even $x$ is even too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have it obtuse, you need $y \gt x \sqrt 2$.  Also $y$ must be even so that you can divide $2008-y$ by $2$.  What is the smallest $y$ that works?  What is the largest?

Comment: isn't it easier to work out the smallest and largest $x$?